# bash - what am i doing wrong now?

Tags: bash, function, terminal, refactoring

After getting my check for files and dirs working, I decided to break them out into separate functions and make calls instead. What am I doing wrong? And sorry for asking so many questions lately.

```
function checkForFilesInCurrentDir(){
    # check if there are files in the current directory
    doFilesExist=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`
    if [ -z "$doFilesExist" ]; then
        echo "no files"
        return 0 
    else
        echo "some files"
        return 1
    fi
}

function checkForDirsInCurrentDir(){
    # check if there are dirs excluding . and .. in the current directory
    doDirsExist=`find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`
    if [ -z "$doDirsExist" ]; then
        echo "no dirs"
        return 0
    else
        echo "some dirs"
        return 1
    fi
}
# function to cd to the next non-empty directory or next branching directory
function cdwn(){
    # check if there are files in current dir
    filesInDir=`checkForFilesInCurrentDir`
    dirsInDir=`checkForDirsInCurrentDir`
    if [[ "$filesInDir" -eq 1 ]]  && [[ "$dirsInDir" -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "now is a good time to cd"
    else
        echo "dirs or files detected"
    fi
}
```

before I was returning true/false and testing in teh same way but I changed to returning 1/0 just in case, but that doesnt seem to be the problem. This is taking way longer than it will ever save me from its usage, so I need to make sure I learn from this so my future endeavours are quicker affairs...

I get the following output when running the program.
sh.exe": [[: no files: syntax error in expression (error token is "files")
dirs or files detected

I should perhaps mention I am on windows 7 using git bash terminal.

Comment: Don't apologize for asking questions as long as you 1: have looked thoroughly for a solution yourself and 2: ask your question in a clear manner. Your question is not that clear to me, try to be more to the point and try to always include a *minimum* of code. By that last sentence I mean to include code but not all of it, just relevant parts or ideally a minimal example in which you can reproduce the anomaly.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong so I don't know the minimum amount of code needed... I make a call to 2 functions. One checks for whether or not there are files in the current directory, the other does the same for directories, excluding . and ..

I think the problem is in the cwdn function, as the other two are definitely working now. For the time being I meerely want to print a message if there are no files or dirs in the current working directory, or print a message saying dirs or files detected otherwise...

Comment: BTW, if you use `find -mindepth 1` you will not find `.` nor `..` so you can also check it using `[ -z ... ]`.

Comment: when I tried it did find . though...

Comment: Then you have a wrong order of arguments for `find` or a very strange version. Try `find . -mindepth 1 -type d` and tell me you see `.`.

Comment: wait a min, I used maxdepth , which does return .

Comment: Use both, `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`, it's not a problem.

Comment: but isnt mindepth reduntant at that point

Comment: No because mindepth is 0 now, which is why it shows `.`. If you try it, you'll notice different output so there can be no redundancy. - Anyway, this is just a side note, I have supplied an answer and if you want to I will explain it in greater detail.

Comment: I ran with mindepth 1 and maxdepth 1 and it still showed the .

Comment: wait maybe I didn't, I did it again and it looks like it didn't show

Comment: Then your `find` is broken or something lol. - Either way that's not the point of your question so don't mind it.

Comment: Nah, just misread the output. Cleared the terminal and tried another couple of times. my bad

Comment: No worries, check if the answer works, I'd like to solve this, haha.

Comment: You did not implement my fix, you are still checking the variables in which the **output** resides, not the return status. - Read my answer very carefully, especially the part about **$?**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do something like this in `cdwn`

```
 function cdwn {
     # check files in dir and output immediately 
     checkForFilesInCurrentDir
     # store the return value
     ret="$?"

     # check for dirs in dir and output
     checkForDirsInCurrentDir

     if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]] && [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
         echo success
     else
         echo "at least one failed"
     fi
 }
```

You can check the exit status of the last called function by accessing the shell builtin `$?`. This might probably be of great help to you!

Oh and by the way: try to exit using code `0` upon success and use other integers for errors etc.

**Further explanation**

You were trying to check the exit status of the called function (i.e. the **return value**), these are stored in the shell builtin `$?`. Instead you defined your variables in the following manner: `variable=$(some command)`. This will put all the output of the function or command inside the variable.

For example: using `var=$(ls)` will store all files and folders in the variable `var`. But the command ends with `exit 0` which is not shown as output, so it cannot be retrieved from `var`. This exit status is instead saved in `$?`.

In your case you saved the output of `checkForFilesInCurrentDir` to a variable. Since your function echoes either 'some files' or 'no files', this is the content of your variable, not the exit code. So you'd had to check `[[ $filesInDir = "some files" ]]` to check whether there were files found. But it's better to use the exit code, which is stored in `$?`. That way, if the echo changes or you add another echo to the function, you wouldn't have to rewrite the control structure.

Comment: Why shouldn't I store the results of the call in a variable? I find it more readable that way.

Comment: Because you intend to output it anyway, if you weren't you would still not store it but pipe the output to `/dev/null`. Even when you intend to show part of it you'd still be better of piping to `grep`, `awk` or `sed`. It may be more readable to you but it's not the best practice I think. See how my code is much shorter for instance?

Comment: Do you also store output of other commands in variables? E.g. `var=$(ls -l)` to show it later as `echo $var`? No. Why? Because it's overkill. If you'd do that, you could even do this: `var=$(echo 'hello'); echo $var` which is absurd.

Comment: I tried as  you suggested and it works. But I still dont understand what was wrong with my previous method, and it will drive me insane if I don't find out... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well everything that gets outputted to the console was stored in those variables, so they contained the string "no dirs found" or something like that. They never contained `1` nor `0` because those are exit statuses and not console output.

Comment: Please do accept the answer if it worked for you, I will explain in greater detail in a minute. I know what it is you're struggling with, I believe.

Comment: I accepted the answer. I commented out your version and edited my version to look like the following:
function cdwn(){
 # check if there are files in current dir
 filesInDir=`checkForFilesInCurrentDir`
 echo $filesInDir
 echo $?
 dirsInDir=`checkForDirsInCurrentDir`
 echo $dirsInDir
 echo $?
}
and now it echos 

no files 0
some dirs 0

and in the second directory it results in

no files 0
some dirs 0

Comment: `$?` holds the exit code for the last command executed. If you execute `ls` it will be 0, unless something went wrong, then it would be something else. As soon as you execute another command (*any* command) your `$?` will be updated.

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to keep that in mind. I will now try cd into the sole directory in the event that there are no files or dirs, and loop until there are files or dirs... I hope I don't have to ask another question. Its 3am so I should really call it a night! Thanks for your help. Its been painful but I have learned quite a bit!

Comment: No problem, remember to not be afraid of asking questions and definitely never apologize for it. That's exactly what we're here for.

Comment: Appreciated! Hopefully before long I'll be answering questions, rather than asking them. Though I suspect I'll have to ask many more questions before that day...

Comment: Meh, just buy a decent book on bash!